# How to limit number of records returned using this.store.find in a route

Tags: ember.js

I have the following code in my Index route. How do I limit the number of records returned? I have this._super(controller, model) set in the route's setupController.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      articles: this.store.find('article'),
      categories: this.store.find('category', {limit: 3})
    });
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    // No records are retrieved without this
    this._super(controller, model);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

That's ok. I re-read an Ember.js tutorial and realised `limit` is just a parameter for my API; so I set it in my Rails API controller and got it working.

```
  def index
    if params[:limit].present?
      @articles = Article.limit(params[:limit])
    else
      @articles = Article.all
    end
    render json: @articles
  end
```

You can also further limit the stored records using [slice](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html#method_slice) in Ember.js:

```
categories: this.store.find('category', {limit: 10}).then(function(result) {
  return result.slice(0,3);
})
```

Big thanks to @locks on the #ember.js IRC chatroom.